# send data at known rate to usb port

Tags: windows, tcl

I have a Windows TCL application that controls individual chips on a board via the USB port. I'm using an FTDI driver in bitbang mode.  Bitbang mode makes the USB device on the board act like a PC parallel port.

Let's say the chip on the board is a binary counter.  If I want to make the counter increment, I would write a series of bytes to the USB port that would cause the chip to count.

If I want the counter to count at some rate, I would send those bytes at some known rate.

Since the data is binary data, I configure the port for binary mode.  I write the few control bytes (call it a chunk) to a buffer, then flush the port so the data posts to the USB port (so it does the count when I want). After the write, I wait for some time, then write the chunk again.

I know this will not be perfectly timed; that doesn't matter; I just need close this time.

My problem is that data won't transfer faster than about 2mS between chunks.  (I'm not talking about the transfer rate of the data within the chunk, I'm talking about the minimum time between chunks.)  Another way to say it is, it seems the minimum time to service a flush of a buffer of any (practical) size is about 2mS.

I measured 2mS by observing the data changes with an o-scope. This agrees with timers I've put into my code as well.

Is there any way to make this interval time shorter?  I don't know if it is the actual execution timeslice I get from windows, or if it is the queue processing interval of the buffer transfer to the USB.  Is there a way to figure out what is causing the delay in the OS?

Is there a way to control this interval.  It would be great to get this to 500uS instead of 2mS.

Just hoping someone can make a suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling with this exact same problem a couple of months ago.

By examining the USB traffic it turned out that, when in bitbang mode, the FTDI driver was constantly polling the FTDI chip for newly available data, causing the delay between put operations on the bus and taking a good chunk of CPU resources when more than one FTDI board was connected to the same PC.

This behavior was consistent in both Windows and Linux. In Windows you can check this by using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) and [USBPcap](http://desowin.org/usbpcap/).

In my case I had a FPGA on the FTDI board. Offloading the more time-sensitive tasks to the FPGA and sending commands in batches worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually running into the polling interval for the FTDI device.  I believe based on my experience that it defaults to 2 msec, though my quick Google search was not conclusive.  I did find it mentioned that the supported polling intervals for their drivers were 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 or 32 msecs.

This is an FTDI driver/USB spec limitation, not a Tcl or even Windows issue.  You may be able to configure the driver to push the polling interval down to 1 msec, but I think that's likely to be the best you can do.